# Logic Input Current Definition

Tags: current, digital-logic

I want to control shutdown pin of this IC MAX9920 using digital output of arduino.

https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX9918-MAX9920.pdf

My question regards to this:
In the datasheet page 6 says shutdown input current max 10ua. So if digital output of arduino when is high is 5v, do I have to put a 600k or 800k between this pin and the ic shutdown pin?

I ask this for 2 reasons:

Because I don't want to damage ic when digital output pin of arduino is high.
To understand logic input current definition.

Comment: That spec is the minimum current the input requires. If you comply with the voltage specs, then you don’t need to limit the current.  For point of comparison, a LS TTL device might require 1mA to pull its input low and 400uA to pull it high.

Comment: Thanks so much Kartman!

Comment: As I said, if you comply with the voltage specs for the input, then there will be no damage. The arduino will have a similar spec for its inputs. Another way of interpreting the spec is the minimum amount of force needed to move the input. As long as >10uA is available, the input will move. The input will not consume more current than it needs -except if you exceed the voltage specs.

Comment: That is a great answer!! Perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need a resistor.  That 5 uA input current value is the maximum current the driving device, the Arduino in your case, has to be able to supply to the SHDN pin.  This spec holds so long as the voltage on the SHDN pin is within the range specified in the table on page 6, between 0 V and Vcc.